# When is $\left\{\begin{pmatrix} x & yb \\ y & x \\ \end{pmatrix} : x,y\in \mathbb{Q}\right\}$ an integral domain?

Tags: matrices, ring-theory, integral-domain

Any hint about this exercise I am struggling with?

Let $b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and

$$A=\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}
    x & yb  \\
    y & x  \\
    \end{pmatrix} : x,y\in \mathbb{Q}\right\}.$$
Now, $A$ is a commutative sub-ring of $M(2,\mathbb{Q})$, prove that $A$ is an integral domain $\iff$ $b$ is not a square in $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Think about determinants.

Comment: Alternatively, show $$f : \frac{\mathbb{Q}[x]}{(x^2-b)} \to A$$ defined by $$f(a_0 + a_1 x) = \left(\begin{array}{cc} a_0 & a_1b \\ a_1 & a_0\end{array}\right)$$ is a well-defined ring homomorphism (it's obviously bijective)

Comment: @BrianMoehring this clarifies everything, thank you!